# OLS / MLS estimation with sum of the beta = 1?

Tags: multiple-regression, estimation, least-squares

In my research I am using an OLS multiple linear regression like:
$$
y_i = x_i^T\beta + \varepsilon_i
$$

$y_i$ and $x_i$ are some 2-by-1 matrices (forecasts from 2 different models).

Now I want to perform OLS (which I am able to). The problem is that the elements of the $\beta$ can be negative and the sum is not necessarily $1$. Do you know any reference or algorithm to impose these restrictions?

$$\sum \beta = 1\text{  and  }\beta_j\ge 0\ \   \forall j$$

Comment: Basically, you are constraining the solution obtained from OLS to be on the unit ball.  If I recall correctly, you can achieve this via regularization.

Comment: As response y_i is a matrix, beta is a matrix too. I am curious what kind of situation requires sum(beta) = 1?

Comment: http://stanford.edu/class/ee103/lectures/constrained-least-squares/constrained-least-squares_slides.pdf

Comment: What is *MLS estimation*?

Comment: sorry guys for confusing. I am beginner... I wanted to refer to multiple linear regression... Demetri's reference is exactly what I was searching -> CLS

Comment: Our site has many answers to this question: please search for [regression linear constraint](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+linear+constraint).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand what you mean by "...are some 2-by-1 matrices".

But in the standard case, this is a quadratic programming problem with equality constraints. As a starter take a look [at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Equality_constraints).

However your problem simplifies. Your condition reads as
$$\sum_{r=1}^k \beta_r = 1 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \beta_k = 1 - \sum_{r<k} \beta_r.$$

Hence your model can be rewritten as:
$$y_i-x_{i,k} = \sum_{r<k} (x_{i,r}-x_{i,k})\beta_r +\varepsilon_i$$

Now define $y_i^* = y_i-x_{i,k}$ as well as $x_{i,r}^*:=(x_{i,r}-x_{i,k})$ ($r<k$) 
and let $y^*$ and $X^*$ be the corresponding "matrices".

Estimation procedure is then straightforward:

First use unrestricted OLS to get the $(k-1)$ coefficients from the regression of $y^*$ on $X^*$.

Then set $\beta_k = 1 - \sum_{r<k} \beta_r$ and you should be done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I am realizing from demetri's link that I am searching for CLS -> constrained least squares. I guess thats what you are explaining here. I will try to implement in matlab. thanks

Comment: "some 2-by-1 matrices". I just want to say that I have 2 points for each observation point. Like k=2.

Comment: Does your simplification also holds for the condition $\beta_r\ge 0\ \   \forall r$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Succesfully implemented in Matlab

```
A = [];
b = [];
Aeq= ones(1,size(Y_i,2)); %construct sum condition
beq = [1]; %condition that the sume of weights must be 1
lb = zeros(1,size(Y_i,2)); %non-negative condition for any weight
ub = ones(1,size(Y_i,2)); %condition that no weight can be bigger than 1

%some starting values
p=ones(size(Y_i,2),1)
p=p./size(Y_i,2) %-> equal values for all models/estimations


weights = fmincon(@LSQreg,p,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)




function sumres = LSQreg(p)

global Y_i
global D_i

w=p;

err =   D_i  - sum(w'.*Y_i,2);


sumres = sum(err.^2);

end
```

the result is perfectly satisfying the constraints